# Power BI Relationship if in range

Tags: powerbi, relational-database, ssas, dax, data-modeling

I have a table like (Table A) (Actual size more than 100 million records)

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 90 | A |
| 110 | B |

And another one (Table B)

| ID_MIN | ID_MAX | CAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 100 | Cat1 |
| 102 | 115 | Cat2 |

I want create relationship between these tables in POWER BI for modelling. It must be like; IF (Table A) ID between ID_MIN and ID_MAX.

I can do it in sql easily like ; ... on ID>=ID_MIN and ID<=ID_MAX

But in power BI there is no option like that.

And also I do not want to create column with join in my fact table because it is extremly large.

You need to know that for real Table B has more columns which I want to see em in my data model.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done either by a measure or by a calculatedcolumn (in Tabel_A)

Measure

```
ID_CAT = 
var thisID = MAX('Table_A'[ID])

return  
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table_B'[CAT]),
    'Table_B'[ID_MIN] <= thisID,
    'Table_B'[ID_MAX] >= thisID
)
```

Then in a visual table, add [ID] from 'Table_A' and then this measure.

Or you can create a calculated column in Table_A like this:

```
CAT_COLUMN = 
var thisID = [ID]
var temptab = 
FILTER(
    'Table_B',
    'Table_B'[ID_MIN] <= thisID &&
    'Table_B'[ID_MAX] >= thisID
)

return
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table_B'[CAT]);
    temptab
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. I created a column in Table A and created S_ID (unique) column in Table B. Filtreleme column;

filtreleme = MAXX(FILTER('Table (4)', EARLIER('Table'[ID])>='Table (4)'[Min_id] && EARLIER('Table'[ID])<='Table (4)'[Max_id]),'Table (4)'[S_id])

Then I created relationship between table A and Table B by using filtreleme and S_ID. Then it solved.